# Edit Field Dependency Doesn't having the values as per the PICKLIST Fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

Salesforce Field Dependency Values are not showing in edit Field Dependency

Values for field Dependency is not visible as per the picklist
I have checked the record types also but still it is having the issue
I have roughly around 800 picklist values in my Picklist field, there are some values which are not present in the edit field dependency, and I also have some unwanted values in that edit field dependency also, Please kindly  help me to get through this problem

I cant able to think any of solution, I have only checked the Picklist values, Global Value Sets and Record Types. I can able to find 'Plastic Bottle' in Picklist Field Value, Global Sets Value and In Record Types also, But I cant able to find the value in EDIT FIELD DEPENDENCY